# What's the way to achieve conditional presentation for view model with MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a login viewmodel (with corresponding page).
In this particular situation I am using Xamarin.Forms.

What I need is the login view to be presented as common view of Navigation Stack as the view which could be annotated with [MvxModalPresentationAttribute].

I show this view in two cases:

- the first view to appears when the app launches and the user not signed in (and further work without signing in);
- during the app work (if the user not signed in), but the user requested some functionality, which requires signing in first.

I guess, Custom Presenter is the way to achieve that, like this (for iOS, as example):

```
public class GeneralPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter
{
    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        // ...

        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

However, I am not quite following what should be next steps. (Especially, if there is anything specific in regards to Xamarin.Forms should be also done).

Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

on Mvvmcross.core 5.7.0, If you want to present a view with modal style on iOS, you can add a `MvxModalPresentation` attribute to the view:

```
[MvxModalPresentation(
        // Add this to modify the present view's style
        //ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet,
        //ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
    )]
public class SecondView : MvxViewController
{
    ...
}
```

Then the way to present this view is the same as push:

```
private readonly Lazy<IMvxNavigationService> _navigationService = new Lazy<IMvxNavigationService>(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>);
async private void ExecuteCommand()
{
    await _navigationService.Value.Navigate<SecondViewModel>();
}
```

At last dismiss this view should be like:

```
async private void ExecuteCommand()
{
    await _navigationService.Value.Close(this);
}
```

### Update:

After updating the Mvvmcross to 6.0.1.0, we can use the `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` interface to define a view's presentation style. Make the view implement the interface:

```
public class SecondView : MvxViewController<SecondViewModel>, IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute
{
    ...
    public MvxBasePresentationAttribute PresentationAttribute(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var instanceRequest = request as MvxViewModelInstanceRequest;
        SecondViewModel viewModel = instanceRequest?.ViewModelInstance as SecondViewModel;

        if (viewModel.IsModalView)
        {
            return new MvxModalPresentationAttribute();
        }
        return new MvxChildPresentationAttribute();
    }
    ...
}
```

`IsModalView` is defined in my ViewModel. when we want to present a view, use this to modify the style:

```
public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel<bool>
{
    ...
    public override void Prepare(bool parameter)
    {
        IsModalView = parameter;
    }
    public bool IsModalView { set; get; }
    ...
}
// The navigate method
await _navigationService.Value.Navigate<SecondViewModel, bool>(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I am actually asking about (and what's mentioned in the title) is how can I do it **conditionally**. I.e., how I can achieve it to open as popup in one case and as a common-navigation-stack-page in another (dependently on view model conditions).

Comment: Hi @Agat, did it help you?

Comment: Land Lu, that might be because my question was still quite abstract, or you haven't caught it properly, but my concerns were mostly regarding MvvmCross mechanics, but not the way to organize the ViewModel structure. So, could you extend the answer with providing custom MvxFormsPagePresenter example, as this is the second approach possible. Then the answer would be complete and I will mark it so.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your comments. My edit methods provide a workaround that the customized property of ViewModel decides the presentation type of the View. Do you also want to implement that on Forms?

Comment: Actually, the tag of the question mentions XF as well. But the main point was regarding MvvmCross tools to provide ability of conditional presentation (one of those is Custom Presenter).